# I have a mounted USB disk (GoPro camera with SD card) in Debian 12 and am not seeing any data. Why?

Tags: usb, debian, usb-storage, debian-bookworm

I have mounted my external USB disk in Debian 12 (Bookworm). It's showing on the “Other Location” list. But, when I opened it, there is only EFI filesystem data.

It's a USB connected GoPro camera that has an SD card in it.

I have some videos on there. How can I access my data?

How can I mount them as an NTFS/FAT32, or other eligible way to access it?

See the attached images for more info:

Showing filesystem:
[image: Showing Filesystem]

Showing data type
[image: Showing Data type]

Which data only showing:
[image: Which data only showing]

lsblk Data:
[image: lsblk Data]

lsblk -F data:
[image: lsblk -F data]

Comment: What kind of disk is it? Your gnome-disks screenshot doesn't really match the rest... Can you include the output of `lsblk`, `lsblk -f`, and `lsblk -S` as well?

Comment: Please add partition layout to your question. Preferably a screenshot from GPartEd or another partitioning tool.

Comment: What kind of data are you expecting to appear?

Comment: What operating system and version? Is fuse installed? How is the drive partitioned?

Comment: lsblk data added.

Comment: but how can i mount it?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it's bebian 12. idk it's have fuse installed or not.

Comment: Users at GoPro forums say they use an USB SD card reader adapter, they don't try to mount the drive directly by USB cable: https://community.gopro.com/s/question/0D53b00008BtK5BCAV/linux-support?language=es

Comment: @ChanganAuto thank you very much for your kind help. I just got my ans. it's not supported by linux. I really hope that Linux and Go pro will work to fix it.

Comment: Linux has nothing to fix. Vendors do. When proprietary software and/or drivers are needed it's the prerogative of the vendor to publish them or not for any given OS.

Comment: It looks like you are viewing the GoPro Operating System and not the content of your SD Card.